# How to compare two elements from different arrays in Arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've created two arrays with `ArrayList` (java), `aList1` and `aList2`. Both will have a mix of doubles and strings. How do I directly compare the individual contents of `aList1` to their corresponding individual contents in `aList2` For example, if the first value or string in `aList1` doesn't match the first value or string in `aList2`, there should be a message saying that the two don't match. This should go on for every element of each `ArrayList`.

Thanks!

EDITED:

Here was my initial attempt:

```
if (!aList1.get(0).equals(aList2.get(0))) { 
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "#1 is incorrect.");
}
if (!aList1.get(1).equals(aList2.get(1))) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "#2 is incorrect.");
}
```

And so on, by comparing each element from aList1 to aList2, and seeing if they are not equal (whether they be doubles or strings). The corresponding elements and the sizes of the arrays will always be the same. So for example, if aList1 = {0,1,2,3,4,dog}, aList2 could contain {10,2,5,2,cat}.

EDIT: The whole code.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class KevinMath2 {
        static File filename = new File("homework.txt");
        static ArrayList <Object> aList = new ArrayList <Object> ();
        static String homework = " ";
        static File filename2 = new File("homework2.txt");
        static ArrayList <Object> aList2 = new ArrayList <Object> ();
        static String homework2 = " ";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String initialInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to add answers or check answers?");
        String again;
        char repeat;
        do {
            switch (initialInput) {
                case "Add answers":
                    char answerfinal1;
                    String answerPass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the password");
                    while (!answerPass.equals("Victor")) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Incorrect Password. Please try again.");
                        answerPass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the password.");
                    }
                    do {
                        do {
                            String options = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the date of the desired" +
                                                                            " answers to add (M/D/Y)");
                            switch (options) {
                                case "05/29/15":
                                    while (!homework.isEmpty()) {
                                        homework = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the answers, in order. After "
                                                                                + "the last answer, leave the next answer" 
                                                                                + " blank, and click OK.");
                                        if (!homework.isEmpty()) aList.add(homework);
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (filename);
                                        Writer output = new BufferedWriter (fw);
                                        int sz = aList.size();
                                        for (int i=0; i < sz; i++) {
                                            output.write(aList.get(i).toString() + "\n");
                                        }
                                        output.close();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oops! I cannot create that file.");
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Please enter a valid date.");
                                    break;
                            }
                        } while (!homework.isEmpty());
                        String final1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Is this correct: " + aList.get(0) + " "
                                                                        + aList.get(1) + " " + aList.get(2) + " " + 
                                                                        aList.get(3) + " " + aList.get(4) + "? (Yes or No)");
                        answerfinal1 = final1.charAt(0);
                    } while (answerfinal1 == 'n' || answerfinal1 == 'N');

                    break;
                    //Need to store the array permanently
                case "Check answers": //Need to make it so it stores array of Kevin's answers permanently
                    char answerfinal2;
                    String checkPass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the password");
                    while (!checkPass.equals("Kevin")) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Incorrect Password. Please try again.");
                        answerPass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the password.");
                    }   
                    do {
                        do {
                            String options2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the date of the desired" +
                                                                            " answers to check (M/D/Y)");
                            switch (options2) {
                                case "05/29/15":
                                    while (!homework2.isEmpty()) {
                                        homework2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the answers, in order. After "
                                                                            + "the last answer, leave the next answer" +
                                                                             " blank, and click OK.");
                                        if (!homework2.isEmpty()) aList2.add(homework2);
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (filename2);
                                        Writer output = new BufferedWriter (fw);
                                        int sz = aList2.size();
                                        for (int i=0; i < sz; i++) {
                                            output.write(aList2.get(i).toString() + "\n");
                                        }
                                        output.close();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oops! I cannot create that file.");
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Please enter a valid date.");
                            }
                        } while (!homework2.isEmpty());
                        String final2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Is this correct: " + aList2.get(0) + " "
                                + aList2.get(1) + " " + aList2.get(2) + " " + 
                                aList2.get(3) + " " + aList2.get(4) + "? (Yes or No)");
                        answerfinal2 = final2.charAt(0);
                    } while (answerfinal2 == 'n' || answerfinal2 == 'N');

                    int i = 0; // counter variable


                    if (aList.size() == aList2.size()) { // Check if both lists are equal
                        for (Object obj : aList) { // iterate through any list
                            if (obj.getClass() == String.class) { // find if it's a string
                                if (!aList.get(i).equals(aList2.get(i))) {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "#" + i + " is wrong.");
                                }

                            }

                            if (obj.getClass() == Double.class) { // or a double
                                if (!aList.get(i).equals(aList2.get(i))) {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "#" + i + " is wrong.");
                                }
                            }

                            i++;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid option.");
                    break;
                } 
            again = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to check another answer, or "+
                                                    "add another answer? (Yes or No)");
            repeat = again.charAt(0);
        } while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y');
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Thanks for using this program");

    }

}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean from your (fairly vague) description - it would be much easier to help you if you could show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Do you only want to contain aList1[1] to aList2[1], aList1[2] to aList2[2], etc and not aList[1] to aList2[1] then aList2[2], etc?

Comment: It should be noted that having a list with heterogeneous elements (i.e. a list that holds both doubles and strings) will be a lot trickier to work with, since there's no direct comparison between the two types.

Comment: I want to do something like this:

Comment: Check out the post: I edited it.

Comment: "*Short but complete*".... **short** (but complete)..!

Answer (score 2):

Try using a for loop to iterate through the first ArrayList and use the counter ('i' in the example below) from that for loop to compare each of the indices that you loop through using the get method provided by ArrayList.

```
for (int i = 0; i < aList1.size(); i++) {
    if (!aList1.get(i).equals(aList2.get(i)))
        //output whatever you want it to say
}
```

Edit: changed to .equals instead of == as suggestion.  Good catch.

Comment: The above is correct, though please be cautious of the case where aList1.size() is not equal to aList2.size() as the loop may fail to compare items at the end of aList2, or may violate the ending array bound of aList2.

Comment: I dont think they want to do anything if the elements are the same if i read the question correctly, just if they dont equal.  Although i did forget to mention the corner cases.  Careful for if the arrays are different size or you may get an index out of bounds error or not compare an extra index in aList2.  Fix this by starting with a check to see if both aList1 and aList2 have the same .size()

Comment: Isn't .equals() only for strings?

Answer (score 0):

Compare their datatypes of both the elements of your list if they match then try to compare their contents
For comparing the datatype follow the below mentioned code

```
    int a = 10;
    Object o = a;
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

If the datatype matches then try to compare their contents

Answer (score 0):

I agree with coal175s answer but since you say you are mixing types in your arrayLists, you should your the .equals() method to compare them.

```
if !(aList1.get(i).equals(aList2.get(i))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise your `List` object with `Object` generics i.e. `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();` so you can add both `String` and `Double` in your list.

Here is an ideal solution to compare two arrays.

```
List<Object> aList1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> aList2 = new ArrayList<Object>();

aList1.add("abc");
aList1.add(25);

aList2.add("abc");
aList2.add(25);

int i = 0; // counter variable

if (aList1.size() == aList2.size()) { // Check if both lists are equal
    for (Object obj : aList1) { // iterate through any list

        if (obj.getClass() == String.class) { // find if it's a string
            if (aList1.get(i).equals(aList2.get(i))) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (i+1) + " is correct.");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (i+1) + " is incorrect.");
            }

        }

        if (obj.getClass() == Double.class) { // or a double
            if (aList1.get(i).equals(aList2.get(i))) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (i+1) + " is correct.");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (i+1) + " is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        if (obj.getClass() == Integer.class) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Integer is found");
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Your code is very hard to follow, when you write a program please try to follow Java conventions.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class KevinMath2 {
    static File filename = new File("homework.txt");
    static ArrayList<Object> aList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    static String homework = "";
    static File filename2 = new File("homework2.txt");
    static ArrayList<Object> aList2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    static String homework2 = "";
    static String answerPass = "";
    static final int TOTAL_QUESTIONS = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String initialInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter Add answers / Check answers to continue");

        switch (initialInput) {
        case "Add answers":
            answers("Victor", aList, filename);

            int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                    "Would you like to compare your answers?", "Yes/No", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                answers("Kevin", aList2, filename2);
                checkAnswers(aList, aList2);
            }
            break;

        // Need to store the array permanently
        case "Check answers": // Need to make it so it stores array of
                                // Kevin's answers permanently
            answers("Kevin", aList2, filename2);

            if (aList.size() == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Please add answers to compare.");
                answers("Victor", aList, filename);
            }
            checkAnswers(aList, aList2);
            break;

        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid option.");
            break;
        }

        // exit the program
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for using this program");

    }

    public static void answers(String pass, ArrayList<Object> list, File f) {

        answerPass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Please enter the password");
        // validate user
        while (!answerPass.equals(pass)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Incorrect Password. Please try again.");
            answerPass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Please enter the password.");
        }

        // add answers
        String final1 = "";
        do {
            clearFile(f);
            list.clear();

            // validate the date of the answers
            String options = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter the date of the desired" + " answers (MM/DD/YY)");
            // add your answers
            enterAnswers(options, list, f);

            // verify the answers
            final1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Is this correct: "
                    + list.get(0) + " " + list.get(1) + " " + list.get(2) + " "
                    + list.get(3) + " " + list.get(4) + "? (Y/N)");

        } while (final1.charAt(0) == 'n' || final1.charAt(0) == 'N');

    }

    public static void enterAnswers(String options, ArrayList<Object> list,
            File f) {

        switch (options) {
        case "05/29/15":
            boolean valid = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                while (!valid) {
                    homework = JOptionPane
                            .showInputDialog("Please enter your answer for question "
                                    + (i + 1));
                    if (!homework.isEmpty())
                        valid = true;
                }
                list.add(homework);
                valid = false;
            }

            writeFile(f, list); // write the answers to a file

            break;

        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid date.");
        }
    }

    public static void writeFile(File filename, ArrayList<Object> list) {
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);
            Writer output = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                output.write(list.get(j) + "\n");
            }
            output.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Oops! I cannot create that file.");
        }
    }

    public static void clearFile(File filename) {
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);
            Writer output = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            output.write("");
            output.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Oops! I cannot create that file.");
        }
    }

    public static void checkAnswers(ArrayList<Object> a, ArrayList<Object> b) {
        int i = 0; // counter variable

        if (a.size() == b.size()) { // Check if both lists are
                                    // equal
            for (Object obj : a) { // iterate through any list
                if (obj.getClass() == String.class) { // find if it's a
                                                        // string
                    if (!a.get(i).equals(b.get(i))) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "#" + i
                                + " is wrong.");
                    }

                }

                if (obj.getClass() == Double.class) { // or a double
                    if (!a.get(i).equals(b.get(i))) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "#" + i
                                + " is wrong.");
                    }
                }

                if (obj.getClass() == Integer.class) { // or an integer
                    if (!a.get(i).equals(b.get(i))) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "#" + i
                                + " is wrong.");
                    }
                }

                i++;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer is based on the assumption

- Add answers to an ArrayList.
- Compare your answers from another ArrayList.
- You aren't comparing your answers from the written files.

You are writing your 'Added answers' to a file, but you aren't reading that file back again to compare against your 'Check answers'. To do that, write another method to read in the `homework.txt` file, store each line to your `aList`, then compare against `aList2`.

Comment: I tried using this method, but for some reason, the program just skips over it...

Comment: @Vctrm6 What exactly is it skipping? Did you put this code in your main? Please take a look at this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ej87c733uxyptdd/CompareArrayList.java?dl=0), and try it out. It should be working fine.

Comment: It goes from the previous code to the code right after; this method just doesn't execute..

Comment: Maybe it's that my previous case isn't storing the two arrays in a text file...am I doing that right?

Comment: @Vctrm6 if you add `Integer` to your list, the code will skip checking. As you have mentioned in your question, you only wanted to check against Strings and Doubles. Please make sure your code takes in double.

Comment: Add this after the last if statement to see if you are taking in your numbers as doubles or integers 
`if (obj.getClass() == Integer.class) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Integer is found");
    }`

Comment: @Vctrm6 it is a very bad practice to put all your code in the `main`. Please put each of your tasks into a new method e.g. `public static void addAnswers()` then call them from the `main`.

Comment: Ok thanks. What about the part of the code that saves the array into a txt file? Is that ok?

Comment: @Vctrm6 I edited my answer above and added my solution to your code. You are writing your answers to a text file, but you haven't read in the file to compare. I'd suggest you to create a `readFile()` method, store each line to a `ArrayList` then compare with your answers.

Comment: @Vctrm6 I hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks so much man, it made things clearer. And you're right, I'm going to need to read the file and compare answers.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider:

1. Do both ArrayList have the same size
2. When you're checking elements, must they be the same data type, or can we cast everything to a String and then compare.  I will assume they must be the same data type.

Having said that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1234, 123.45, "999", 444.444, 999.999));
    List<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1234", 123.45, "9991", 444.444));

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        // Only check against parallel list if the index is in the bounds
        if (i < list2.size()) {
            // Check if the data types match
            if (!list1.get(i).getClass().getName().equals(list2.get(i).getClass().getName())) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s: %s != %s: %s", 
                        list1.get(i).getClass().getName(), list1.get(i), 
                        list2.get(i).getClass().getName(), list2.get(i)));
            }
            // Check if the values match if the datatypes match
            else if (!list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i))) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s != %s", list1.get(i), list2.get(i)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results (999.999 from list1 does not get checked):

```
java.lang.Integer: 1234 != java.lang.String: 1234
999 != 9991
```